# Rails Button save preexisting data from one table to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im a total noob at Ruby on rails.

I've been told to create a button that once clicked saves a bunch of information thats inside the page along with the user and date.

I know that the command 'current_user' and 'datetime.now' can be used. ITs the whole setting up the controllers and linking them into the database.

Sorry if this has been asked before but i could do wih alot of help with this (please just don't link me off to a tutorial, a dumbed down word for word will be great)

Sam

Comment: What button? You mean you want to submit a form? Please include more specifics.

Comment: You need to have something for us to work with and/or fix.  Otherwise, you are asking us to post the tutorial you don't want to be linked to.